# vue.js remove object from list with two-way binding

Tags: vue.js

I have an array of items that I want to display as the rows of a table. However the rows themselves have inputs, allowing the properties of those items to be edited and emitted back up through v-model into the parents `rows` array. when i try to delete a row through button in the child that emits the `removeRow` event, the correct item in the parent's array is deleted but the html only removes the last row of the array.

```js
      <tbody>
        <row-component
          v-for="(row, idx) in rows"
          :key="idx"
          v-model="rows[idx]"
          @removeRow="expenses.splice(idx, 1)"
        ></row-component>
      </tbody>
```

I think I'm doing something fundamentally wrong, but can't seem to figure out how else to menage a dynamic list of javascript objects that are bound via v-model (or otherwise).

I'll try and prepare a codepen with my problem.

Comment: It looks like you're going to need a better choice of `key`. Is there some sort of id in each row that you could use? If not, could you add one? Using the index will cause the template to treat rows with the same index as equivalent, no matter which row you remove. So when you remove a row the template will just perceive that as the last row being removed.

Comment: Expanding upon what was said above, for simple objects, `:key="JSON.stringify(row)"` would be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. There's no unique identifier because the items are created by pushing empty objects into `rows`. Hence it's also not possible to use your json serialization trick, since adding multiple new items would result in duplicates. I've also tried to generate a uuid inside the child component, but that just runs into a endless v-for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use array indexes to identify elements (keys) in Vue, because with some operations this numbering refreshes. After removing an element from the center of the array, the elements after this position receive a new index value. After removing an element from a 5-element array, with indexes from 0 to 4, you get a 4-element array with indexes from 0 to 3. Vue sees this change as deleting key 4 (last row). Create your own indexes when adding data inside this data.

```js
Vue.component("table-component", {
  template: "#table-template",
  data() {
    return {
      rows: [
        { id: 1, name: "A" },
        { id: 2, name: "B" },
        { id: 3, name: "C" },
        { id: 4, name: "D" },
        { id: 5, name: "E" }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    removeRow(id) {
      this.rows = this.rows.filter(row => row.id !== id);
    }
  }
});

Vue.component("row-component", {
  template: "#row-template",
  props: ["value"]
});

new Vue().$mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table-component :rows="rows" />
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="table-template">
  <table v-if="rows.length" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
    <tbody>
      <row-component v-for="(row, idx) in rows" :key="row.id" v-model="rows[idx]" @removeRow="removeRow"></row-component>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>
<script type="text/x-template" id="row-template">
  <tr>
    <td>{{value.id}}</td>
    <td>{{value.name}}</td>
    <td><button @click="$emit('removeRow', value.id)">X</button></td>
  </tr>
</script>
```